# Cordova redrawing/tiling performance

Tags: cordova

I'm building an app using Cordova and encountering a number of issues with performance when running on the device. The app has been developed using Backbone and it performs really well in the browser.

The main issue I would like to resolve is changing between different pages and when the app initially loads, there seems to be an ugly 'tiling effect' as the page is drawing/redrawing.

The code I am using to change between different backbone views is as follows:

```
$('#app-view').empty();
$('#app-view').html($(view.el));
```

Is there a better way to change all the content which performs better in the Cordova webview?

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues in phonegap really stem from the amount of content the webview has to render.  From there it breaks into two categories: ios and android.

For you, I have two suggestions:

**Suggestion #1:**

iOS webview normally out performs the android view.  I've developed several phonegap apps with some basic HTML driven animations and such.

For android THE big thing for android devices is to DISABLE hardware acceleration at either the code level or in your application manifest.xml.

I know this sounds funny, but what it actually does is actually allow the webview to use more of the hardware accelleration.

For me this ended up looking like this:

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**Suggestion #2:**

Instead of doing 
$('#app-view').empty();
$('#app-view').html($(view.el));

Would it be possible for to do something like this:

$('#app-view1').css('display', 'none');
or
$('#app-view1').remove();

and then follow up by simply showing the second set of content, versus completely rendering/downloading for the first time, IE.
$('#app-view1').css('display', 'block');

The core of this second suggestion is to simply toggle the visibility of the two contents, rather than completely resetting all of the html content. You could even set the content into the hidden div, and then toggle the visibility.

I believe that change, when combined with your hardware accelleration settings, should make a measurable difference.

The sooner you can get your html loaded into the hidden div the better, then simply make it visible. When its loaded into the hidden div that gives the html parser time to parse, download resources, etc.